# How to stylize JFoenix for JavaFX Scene Builder nodes and classes in CSS?

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I'm trying to add my custom values to a `JFXButton` property class in the CSS stylesheet but I can't make these work:

```css
.eliminarBtn {
    -fx-background-color: #eb490f; //This work
    -fx-font-color: WHITE; //This doesn't work
    -fx-font-weight: bold; //This doesn't work. Edit: had to refresh(works) 
    -fx-font-size: 20px; //this work
    -fx-background-radius: 8px; //This work
}
```

In this case, I know some of its values because Scene Builder has a drop-down to choose which and then I can type it out in the stylesheet. The others I tried using HTML standard with -fx- and hope to have it running but it didn't. So how do I add weight and color to the button text instead? By the way, I can set the CSS classes for any button node I need too.

Also, if you have a guide for JavaFX styles and/or JFoenix components please add me the link. Thanks.

Comment: [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: @M.S. Awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) for more information about JavaFX's components' style classes and their default values.

`JFXButton` extends JavaFX's `Button` and it seems to add only one extra CSS property which is `-jfx-button-type`, the two possible values are `FLAT` (default) and `RAISED`. Answering your question, you can change the color and weight of a `JFXButton`'s text using the following CSS:

```
.button {
    -fx-text-fill: WHITE;
    -fx-font-weight: BOLD;
}
```

A raised `JFXButton` can be created in CSS like this:

```java
JFXButton raisedButton = new JFXButton("RAISED BUTTON");
button.getStyleClass().add("button-raised");
```

```css
.button-raised {
    -jfx-button-type: RAISED;
    -fx-background-color: TURQUOISE;
    -fx-text-fill: WHITE;
    -fx-font-weight: BOLD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Scene Builder, the properties panel at the right side tells you the options available to modify: for example you can fill the text in the "Text Fill" area. However to implement the code you must add fx like so:

```
-fx-text-fill: #colorvalue;
```

And so on for the other modifiers. However, there are modifiers that accept more than 1 value which I do not know of. Maybe those formats follow the css rules, you must start there too.